# Having Trouble with Authentication for Python CoreAPI

Tags: python, core-api

I have tried the two documented methods for authentication, but both yield  403 Forbidden, detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."

```
auth = coreapi.auth.TokenAuthentication(
scheme='Token', token='token')
```

and

```
auth = coreapi.auth.BasicAuthentication(
username='user',
password='password')

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/schema/'
client = coreapi.Client(auth=auth)
schema = client.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code of `coreapi.auth.BasicAuthentication` and `coreapi.auth.TokenAuthentication` [here](https://github.com/core-api/python-client/blob/master/coreapi/auth.py), you need to instantiate the authentication object as follows :

```
auth = coreapi.auth.TokenAuthentication(
scheme='Token', token='token', domain='domain')
```

or

```
auth = coreapi.auth.BasicAuthentication(
username='user',
password='password',
domain='domain'  
)
```

Comment: Hi MedAli, Thanks for your comments. I tried your adjustment to my authentication, but am still getting "Authentication credentials were not provided." when trying to retrieve the schema.

Comment: @DavidG use requests instead it's better an easier to use. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: ... Strangely the authentication I used has served to authenticate other requests of the format client.get(get_document_url), returning an OrderDict. (The same request without authentication returns "Authentication credentials were not provided.") So the authentication seems to work for other urls, but not for retrieving schema ...

Comment: @DavidG maybe it's a question of permission? since I can't reproduce the error, I can't help much..